# How to simulate pressing the back button in Robolectric?

Tags: java, android, robolectric, instrumentation

Is there an easy way to simulate pressing the back button in Robolectric?

The following test fails:

```
@Test
public void testBackButtonClosesActivity() throws Exception {
    ShadowActivity activityShadow = Shadows.shadowOf(activity);
    activity.onKeyDown(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK, new KeyEvent(0, 0, KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK, 0));
    assertTrue(activityShadow.isFinishing());
}
```

However, this succeeds:

```
@Test
public void testBackButtonClosesActivity() throws Exception {
    ShadowActivity activityShadow = Shadows.shadowOf(activity);
    activity.onBackPressed();
    assertTrue(activityShadow.isFinishing());
}
```

This is in my activity to override `onKeyDown()`:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK & myCondition) {
        doStuff();

        return true;
    } else {
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

Testing when `myCondition` is true triggers `doStuff()` in another test using `activity.onKeyDown(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK, new KeyEvent(0, 0, KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK, 0));`.

The activity is created using:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(ShadowApplication.getInstance().getApplicationContext(), MyActivity.class);
    activity = Robolectric.buildActivity(MyActivity.class).withIntent(intent).create().visible().get();
```

I should point out that pressing the back button in the app when myCondition is false results in the activity closing.

Comment: Can you explain why onBackPressed is not enough? Why do you need to exactly handle back button key?

Comment: I have moved to using onBackPressed(). The original code I was working with used onKeyDown() and I didn't want to refactor unnecessarily.

Comment: I need `onPause()` to be called after back key press. The running app propagates the event from `onBackPressed()` to `onPause()`, but in Robolectric invoking `onBackPressed()` does not call `onPause()`. Have you found a solution yet, or do i have to call `ActivityController<T>.pause()` manually?

Comment: If you your logic changes something in `onBackPressed()` and then something happens based on that data when `onPause()` is called, then you could call `onBackPressed()` followed by `onPause()`. It is probably better practice to have two tests: one testing `onBackPressed()` and one testing `onPause()`. You could also use robolectric which should call `onPause()` as it would happen in a real app. If you are still having difficulty I would suggested creating a new question on Stack Overflow and posting your code.